# What logging will show me my sensitivity to single core vs multi core performance on desktop linux

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

I want to have an informed opinion about how much I should value single core performance over multi-core for my use on an 8 core desktop.

This is to help me commit to Intel or AMD over the next generation of CPUs, particularly on the desktop.

There seems to be a trade-off between single core performance and multicore between AMD and Intel. The benchmarks of single core and multicore are well known, but my problem is how I should objectively weight single core vs multicore performance for what I do. I think that a week of measurements would be a good sample.

I thought that a measure of single core bottleneck could be when one core is more than "80%" active while the other cores are close to idle. Cores have different frequencies so I don't know how to normalise "80%", meaning a busy single-core period of time. Maybe when CPU frequency of one core is 80% to 100% of maximum and the other cores are simultaneously < 10%.

And then for multicore, probably a well-performing multicore CPU is really only an advantage when my work load is > (say) 80% of all core capacity ... If "AMD" stands for the CPU with weaker single core but better multicore, and "Intel" is the opposite, then I have a workload that consumes 50% of a candidate "AMD" CPU (AMD means high multicore capacity) multicore capacity, it might consume say 70% of a candidate "Intel" multicore, but the Intel CPU is not a bottleneck until it gets to 100%. It is only when the multicore load goes beyond the ceiling of the "Intel" CPU that I have a multicore-bottle neck with "Intel". This threshold would depend on exactly what CPUs I consider, it means that I would filter the load to see how often it is above that threshold, whatever it is. Then I could estimate how much faster each CPU would be at the single core constraint and the multi core constraint, and work out which saves me the most time.

I am ignoring energy consumption and everything else. The thing that matters much more than anything else is the response of the machine while I am at the keyboard.

Since I doubt I am the first person to have this question, open to suggestions :) I imagine people running lots of servers do this all the time but I haven't found a good answer.

Comment: This is ultimately an opinion based question. There are no generic rules for this and it is all based on applications, OS’s and usage. So if you ask me unless you can provide more actual specifics of your intended use, this question is really not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the application not the CPU.
If the application is multi threaded then it will split itself across the cores of you system.
If one of those threads has a greater compute need than the core can give then the application will be limited by the throughput of that core.
In this case the single core speed matters.

This problem is most often with threads that are compute bound.
If it is not then thread will pause while the non-compute work happens and be reschedule.

Do you have any idea if your application has a high compute requirement.
In not the responsiveness of the system will depend on the mix of other application running on the system.